# How to change Input on switch function to class for multiple items

Tags: jquery, class, input, onchange

I have a working jQuery Function which detects if an input is checked then it outputs a notification message and updates the html value and updates mysql via php ajax. Everything is working fine on a single page but I really can't figure out how to implement it for several items on a page. Here is what I got in jQuery.

The Structure is the same on both sites, but I don't know where to start or got no good idea.

Feel Free to add classes or something to get it started or to run please.

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var checkBox = elem;
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    $('.alert-box').remove();
    var currentValue = $(".lovecount").text();
    var newValue = +currentValue + 1;
    $(".lovecount").text(newValue);

    var postid = $("#toggle").attr("data-post");
    var userid = $("#toggle").attr("data-userid");
    //get actual ip

    dataString = 'userid=' + userid + '&postid=' + postid;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'inc/give-love.php',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response) {
      }
    });

    $('<div class="alert-box success" ><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Liebe gegeben!</div>').prependTo('body').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {

      $('.alert-box').remove();

    });
  } else {
    $('.alert-box').remove();
    var currentValue = $(".lovecount").text();
    var newValue = +currentValue - 1;
    $(".lovecount").text(newValue);

    var postid = $("#toggle").attr("data-post");
    var userid = $("#toggle").attr("data-userid");
    //get actual ip

    dataString = 'userid=' + userid + '&postid=' + postid;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'inc/give-love.php',
      data: dataString,
      //beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){

      //check ips from db if actual ip exists 

      //if(1 == 2) //if ip already exists for actual post block submit(success) and display message in button like in success
      //{
      //    xhr.abort();
      //    $("a.btn-default.ja").css("border", "#c85555");
      //    $("a.btn-default.ja").css("background", "#7dc85575");
      //    $('a.btn-default.ja').html("Du hast bereits gevoted für dieses Tutorial"); 
      //    $('a.btn-default.nein').hide(); 
      //}
      //else success  
      //},
      success: function(response) {
      }
    });

    $('<div class="alert-box success" ><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Liebe genommen!</div>').prependTo('body').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {

$('.alert-box').remove();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-favorite" id="heart-container"><a href="#" title="Alle Loves anzeigen"><span class="lovecount">0</span></a>

  <input data-post="123" data-userid="1" type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction(this)">

  <div id="twitter-heart" class=""></div>
  </input>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You have invalid HTML. You cannot wrap a div in an input tag

Comment: #1: Don't Repeat Yourself - DRY

Comment: #2: You need to do stuff in the succes? Then do stuff in the success, not outside the Ajax function

Comment: Allright what do you mean with i made you a script?

Comment: I clicked [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57122304/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and produced a [mcve] (apart from the ajax)

Comment: Allright recognized thanks any idea or solution for my problem like i described a in comment down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you mean this?

```js
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $lovecount = $this.closest("div").find(".lovecount");
  var val = +$lovecount.text() + (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
  $lovecount.text(val)
  $('.alert-box').toggle(!this.checked);

  var postid = $this.attr("data-post");
  var userid = $this.attr("data-userid");
  dataString = 'userid=' + userid + '&postid=' + postid;

  // Are you not supposed to send the new value to the server?

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'inc/give-love.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response) {
      $('<div class="alert-box success" ><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Liebe gegeben!</div>').prependTo('body').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('.alert-box').hide();
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-favorite heart-container"><a href="#" title="Alle Loves anzeigen"><span class="lovecount">0</span></a>
  <input data-post="123" data-userid="1" type="checkbox" class="toggle" />

  <div class"twitter-heart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer buddy but no i mean to use this script which is for id identificator usable fo class and multiple items on the page acually it only works for one.

Comment: See updates. Give everything  a class. The IDs need to go. What about the twitterheart div?

Comment: if you want  i can show you the problem on page would be a little bit easier it would be great to hold the structure and i know its not valide but got a nice effectlet me show you if you want and thanks for the answers man really great.This is the page with multilple inpus and no working with this code [link](https://onepost.eu/neu/postline.php)

Comment: My code is as good as I can do it with the code you provided. The principles are correct, you need to implement them so they match your code on your page

Comment: Man really nice i implemented it and now it updates only the given input but dont jumps back from 1 to zero or 7 to 6 plus is working but no minus any idea

Comment: I missed a bracket: `var val = +$lovecount.text() + (this.checked ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: thanks man is it possible to switch also a simple var a text on toggle in this function ? for the success message if u unlike or a class for example?